# Proving congruent segments in a figure with a right triangle and three squares

Tags: geometry

> The figure is made of three squares and a right triangle.
> How to prove that $\overline{DE}\cong\overline{AF}$?
>
> [image]

Comment: Using coordinate geometry, let $A = (0, 0)$ and let the other two vertices of the triangle be $B = (0, b)$ and $C = (c, 0)$. Then you can find the coordinates of $F$ in terms of $b$ and $c$.

Comment: You've been a Math.SE member long enough to know that the community prefers/expects questions to include something of how the asker has engaged with the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting anyone's time explaining things you know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply  trying to get them to do your homework for you. Isolated problem statements tend to give the wrong impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Are you accepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following picture is self explanatory:

[image]